# Python error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing some image detection. The detection algorithm has a line of code that's causing an error.

The line of code:

```
im_rois = im_rois.astype(np.float, copy=False)
```

The error is:

```
Error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I printed the contents of im_rois. They are:

```
[[ array([[  56.04,   57.32,  317.16,  285.16],
       [ 125.16,   17.64,  332.52,  285.16],
       [   1.  ,    1.  ,  427.24,  639.72],
       ..., 
       [ 201.96,    1.  ,  248.04,   50.92],
       [ 286.44,    1.  ,  350.44,   47.08],
       [ 304.36,  244.2 ,  338.92,  349.16]])]]
```

Curious if anyone can point me in the direction.

Comment: You don't seems to have a `array` but a `list` of `list` of `array`!! You can try `im_rois = im_rois[0][0]`.

Comment: I think it's best to ask the author of `im_rois.astype`. Either to provide more meaningful error, or debug their code.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't passed in an invalid argument to a function in the code you are using?  The name `im_rois` suggests a sequence of "regions of interest", which (maybe) should be an array with shape (N, 4), where N is the number of RoIs.  It looks like your `im_rois` is nested too deep.

Comment: Thanks, yes its quite possible I've got some invalid inputs. The roi inputs are generated by another algorithm called selective search using matlab. The matlab file is loaded and converted into a roi array. I'm trying to figure out if I should go back and fix my matlab based code or persist with the matlab output I have.

Comment: Is this matlab file a `.mat`?  Do you load it with `scipy` `loadmat`?  Matlab matrices load as numpy arrays, but matlab cells load as python lists (but may contains arrays).

Comment: @hpaulj You're right. It's a problem with the inputs. The order of the four items in array item is different from matlab code to the selective search code. To fix, I have to re-write little bits of the matlab code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your error with this sequence:

```
In [1317]: im=[[np.array([[1,2,3]])]]  # list containing array
```

`im.astype(float)` would produce a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'` because it is a list, not an array.

But I can embed it in an object array:

```
In [1318]: x=np.empty((1,),dtype=object)
In [1319]: x[0]=im    
In [1320]: x
Out[1320]: array([[[array([[1, 2, 3]])]]], dtype=object)
```

The `print` looks like yours; note the commas in the inner list.

```
In [1321]: print(x)
[[[array([[1, 2, 3]])]]]
```

If it was a ndim array, the print wouldn't have the commas.

```
In [1325]: print(np.array([[[1,2,3]]]))
[[[1 2 3]]]
```

Now when I try a `astype` I get your value error.

```
In [1322]: x.astype(np.float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1322-1bc194707569> in <module>()
----> 1 x.astype(np.float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But without knowing how `im_rois` is created I can't suggest ways of avoiding this.  If `im_rois` were

```
array([[  56.04,   57.32,  317.16,  285.16],
       [ 125.16,   17.64,  332.52,  285.16],
       [   1.  ,    1.  ,  427.24,  639.72],
       ...]])
```

it wouldn't give this error.

I'd check to make you sure you are feeding this package the right kinds of input, whether it be a list, an array or a scalar.

`vstack` is able to remove this intermediate 'object' layer, allowing `astype`.

```
In [1343]: np.vstack(x)
Out[1343]: array([[[[1, 2, 3]]]])
```